# Swift - How to insert view after every x amount of items in foreach loop

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

**I am trying to create a Foreach loop in a LazyVGrid where a full width view is shown on it's own row after a certain amount of items.**

I'm currently ***having a hard time getting the view to show in the Foreach loop***, I have to place it outside of the loop but then I'm unable to get the current index/indices. Using a Int for a counter didn't work either.

```
LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 30) {
    ForEach(myArray.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        MyView()
        if i > 3 || i > 6 || i > 9 {
            MyOtherView()
        }
    }
}
```

***Also*** trying to figure out how to make the counter dynamic so it works in multiples of 3s -

`i > 3 || i > 6 || i > 9`

Not sure how to go about ***getting the view to show in the Foreach loop on it's own row (in a LazyVGrid) after a certain amount of items***, any suggestions is appreciated.

[image: example img]

Comment: `if I > 0 && I % 3 == 0 { MyOtherView() }`?

Comment: There is an issue with your logic. Use @Larme 's Logic. if this not working for you then you have to explain your problem properly.

Comment: `ForEach` is a `View` not a for loop and `id:\.self` is an error

Comment: @Larme comment lead me closer, I had to change `3` to `2` for it to show after the 3rd item. However because I am inside a ForEach inside a LazyVGrid, I'm still unsure how to make the view a full row on it's own.